# Formik - "dirty" gets applied to all instances with the same custom component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik, yup

**Current Behavior**

When I create a custom input component and try to add a className based on if the input is "dirty" or not, the class gets applied to all the inputs that use this component.

Here's a simple example I created ...
https://codesandbox.io/s/hello-world-h60hj

You'll notice that both inputs use the same custom component "InputComponent", and when you start typing in any one of them, the class gets applied to both of them.

I think the "isValid" is also behaving the same way.

**Expected behavior**

The class should be applied to only the dirty input that I'm typing inside.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieved your output by updating **InputComponent.js**.

```
<div>
  <input
    type="text"
    {...field}
    {...props}
    className={
      !isValid && touched[field.name] && errors[field.name] ? "error" : ""
    }
  />
  {!isValid && touched[field.name] && errors[field.name] && (
    <div className="error">{errors[field.name]}</div>
  )}
</div>
```

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#dirty-boolean

> Returns `true` if values are not deeply equal from initial values, `false` otherwise. `dirty` is a readonly computed property and should not be mutated directly.

I have updated your code here 
https://codesandbox.io/s/hello-world-w7zwt

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Yes I know, I already did that in my project, but that's not what I'm after. I just want to know why is "dirty" gets applied to all inputs with the same custom component?

Comment: For `formik`, `dirty` is indicate throughout the form not for individual `input`. That's why if you update any value in one of the `input` then it become `true`

Comment: I have updated the code. So you can get the idea about the behavior of `dirty` & `error`. Checkout the code https://codesandbox.io/s/hello-world-w7zwt

Comment: Aha, nice. I think "isValid" is the same as "dirty" then because it behaves the same way, right? it is also a Form prop, not a Field prop.